# Appending to array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a problem with this code

```
String[] strLines = null;

while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){
    strLines = strLine.split("\\s");
    System.out.printf("next line - %s\n", strLine);
    for(String asd : strLines) {
        System.out.printf("array element - %s\n", asd);
    }
    System.out.println(strLines.length);
}
```

I'm trying to make a program read from file and then write all unique words into another file. The problem I'm having is that strLines array (which I later convert to Set) is overwritten with every iteration of while loop. Is it possible to somehow append to this array or should I use another way to store my words?

This might be a very beginner question (I've only been coding for a couple of months irregularly), but I couldn't find an answer to it anywhere. Thanks in advance!

Comment: *strLines array (which I later convert to Set)* Don't convert it later to a Set. Instead, create an empty set before the loop, and add every word you read to that set. The strLines array should be declared inside the loop. And it should be named `words`, since it's an array... of words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reason to create an array if all you do with it is converting it to a set later. Simply add to your set in the while loop:

```
String foo = "foo bar baz foo bar baz";
Set<String> fooSet = new HashSet<>();
fooSet.addAll(Arrays.asList(foo.split("\\s")));
```

For your example

```
Set<String> fooSet = new HashSet<>();

while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){
    fooSet.addAll(Arrays.asList(strLine.split("\\s")));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you don't know what the exact size of your array might be, I'd use an ArrayList. An ArrayList does need an import given here: `import java.util.ArrayList` You also need to declare it in a certain way. For an ArrayList full of Strings is this: `ArrayList<String> arrayListOfStrings = new ArrayList<String>();` For an ArrayList of type Object would be this: `ArrayList<Object> arrayListOfObjects = new ArrayList<Object>();` You can make an ArrayList of any type of object. To add an item you use ArrayList's `.add()` function. IE: `arrayListOfObjects.add(indexOfObject)` ArrayLists also have `.get(index)`, `.remove(index)` `.add(index, Object)` `.size()` etc. I hope that you find this brief tutorial on ArrayLists helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `List<String>` collection to store all found words in this way:

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();

    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){
    String[] strLines = strLine.split("\\s");
    words.addAll(Arrays.asList(strLines)); 
    System.out.printf("next line - %s\n", strLine);
    }

    for(String word: words) {
        System.out.printf("word - %s\n", word);
    }
    System.out.println(words.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the answers! All of them have been really helpful, solved my issue with creating a set in the while loop, as [baao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3993662/baao) suggested.

Comment: Please don't post such messages as answers. Answers should just be answers. Instead, upvote the answers you found useful, and optionally post a thank you comment on these answers.